# PHP declared variable, to another file that's included via function

Tags: php, function, include

I have some kind of problem, but i don't get it.. I have an function for including/requiring files, which check is file already included and does exists:

```
function __include($fileclass, $is_required=false) {
    static $already_included = array();
    // checking is set extension of php file, if not append it.
    if (substr($fileclass,-4)!=".php") $fileclass = $fileclass.".php";

    // if already included return;
    if (isset($already_included[$fileclass])) return true;

    // check if file exists:
    if (file_exists($fileclass)) {
        if (!$is_required) include $fileclass;
        else require $fileclass;

        $already_included[$fileclass] = 1;
        return true;
        }
    else {
        if ($is_required) die("can't find required file");
        return false;
        }
}
```

And it works good, but when i started to work on the project, i've used it to include a file, which uses variable from parent file (the one that included it), but it drops notice `Notice: Undefined variable: VARIABLE_NAME`.

So to be clear at coding:

I have two files **file_parent.php** and **file_child.php**, what I've tried:

**file_parent.php:**

```
function __include($fileclass, $is_required=false) { /** i've mentioned it above **/ }
class __CONNECTION {
    private $test;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->test = "SOMETHING";
    }
};
$Connect = new __CONNECTION();
// here i used it to include the children file:
__include('file_child.php');
```

**file_child.php:**

```
print_r($Connect);
```

And i get `Notice: Undefined variable: Connect`.

When i change at **file_parent.php** my function include:

```
__include('file_child.php');
```

to standard include:

```
include 'file_child.php';
```

***Everything will work fine, variable is defined and will be printed.***

I guess there's some problem with `function`, but could someone explain what's the real reason for happening this, **and** is there a possible repair to fix it to including/requiring works through `function` and to not lose variables from previous files.

Thanks!

Comment: `global $Connect` should solve the issue

Comment: When i use `global` i must use `$GLOBALS['Connect']` which i don't want, because as i said, it works fine with regular include.

Comment: have you tried to use require() instead of include to check for maybe misinterpreting?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried, `require` and `include` both of them work, when outside of function, when within function they are including, but the variable still remains undefined.. And as @Tom Doodler said, the `global` can solve it, with using `$GLOBALS['Connect']` but i am looking to do it without `global`..

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do i see, when i printed all defined variables (`get_defined_vars()`), i got this:

```
Array
(
    [fileclass] => test_file2.php
    [is_required] => 
    [already_included] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

So that means the variables are passed, but only one that exists within function (because the function is temporary), so i could make it work to pass variables to `function`, but as it's not the only variable I need so I am gonna use one of two way:

`global` as @Tom Doodler said in comment, and later catch it with `$GLOBALS`

or use `function` to do checks and return just a path if exists/or empty string if file doesn't exists and then just `include/require` it.

Thanks everyone.

*I will not accept this answer, so if someone could better explain the way function behaves in this solution, i will accept that.*